# why I cannot change the font of my back button in UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboardsegue

I want to change the text and font of my navigation controller.

I have a static `UITableView` and when user clicks one cell - I go to the 2nd UIViewController through segue.

I set up the name of the segue in the storyboard and in the code I have:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "myTestSegue") {
        if segue.destination is MyTest {
            print("can I see it?")
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: nil)
        backButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light", size: 20.0)!], for: UIControlState())
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
        }
    }
}
```

now when I run the app and click the cell, I see in the console: `can I see it?`, but the text and font of the button on the next panel doesn't change.

What am I missing?

Comment: I setup your exact same situation with same code and it works for me.  So you have something going on outside of what's explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change font style of back button with this code.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]
 setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
   NSShadowAttributeName:shadow,
   NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0]
   }
 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code;

```
    let customFont = UIFont(name: "Your font Name", size: 17.0)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: customFont!], for: UIControlState.normal)
```